# Firefox Browser in private mode not working - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, browser, private

I'm currently using selenium 3.8 with C#. I tried 2 script's segments below but it's not working.

```
[-----1----]
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.SetPreference("browser.private.browsing.autostart", true);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = firefoxProfile;
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

[-----2----]
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArgument("--private");
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Please help me find a solution?

Comment: Can you try to do this:

Instead of `new FirefoxDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));` 

do `FirefoxDriver(driverService, firefoxProfile, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));`

Basically use other constructor that uses FirefoxProfile `public FirefoxDriver(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile, TimeSpan commandTimeout);`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see nothing change. It's still not working!

Answer (score 0):

go to browser setting - advanced- and clear browsing data .
and open a new incognito mode window then open you

Comment: I think you might be veering off the subject. I'm using Selenium with C#.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single dash.

```
options.AddArgument("-private");
```